# How to check Type belong to in build Dot Net class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having class .

```
Class Employee
{
   int Id {get; set;}
   String Name {get;set;}
   DateTime dob {get;set;}
   Department dept {get;set;}
}

class Department
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   String Name{ get;set;}
}
```

I am getting Employee object.

And I want to get property which are not belong to dot net.
Here String Name, DateTime dob are dot net class.
So i want only Department dept here.

Basically i am traversing the Employee class Property.
And want to check each property whether it belong to dot net or not.
So how to check that.

Comment: What are you saying? dot net class?? In build dot net class?

Comment: the class like String, DateTime , .... etc

Comment: nice to see upvote up to similar questions, I agree (Y)